# Mono android : how to call a number with "#" at the end of it by the application?

Tags: android

When i was trying to make a recharge command using this code :

```
var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:*1400*123456789#"));
StartActivity(callIntent);
```

The "#" latter is not dialed , just the *1400*123456789 part is dialed without # ?

i tried to make it by a variable but failing again !
what is the problem and any solution please ?

Thanks you .

Thank you very much , i found the solution here :
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285

Thanks.

Comment: you should post and accept own answer to this question if you found a solution, to help other people

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use it:

```
var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:*1400*123456789"+Android.Net.Uri.Encode("#")));
StartActivity(callIntent);
```